# Computed Columns in INSERT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPacks]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BatchNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PackID] AS (CONVERT([varchar](50), 'PK' + case when len([ID]) <= (3) then CONVERT([varchar](20), right((0.001) * [ID], (3)), 0) else CONVERT([varchar](20), [ID], 0) end, 0)) PERSISTED,
    [Status] [int] NULL
)
```

Now I Had a New Requirement that Other than this sequence also can be added into this table So that I Will Remove Computed Logic and Create Table As:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPacks]
    (
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [BatchNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [PackID] VARCHAR(50),
        [Status] [int] NULL
    )
```

Now I Want Two Insert Statements which `'PackID'` Should have  logic Which is Similar to this:

```
  AS (CONVERT([varchar](50),'PK'+case when len([ID])<=(3) then
     CONVERT([varchar](20),right((0.001)*[ID],(3)),0) else
     CONVERT([varchar](20),[ID],0) end,0))
```

And A Normal Insert statement which has no logic How can I DO that?

Comment: can you add sample data for PackID ? ID ?

Comment: Edited please Check @Mr.Bhosale

Comment: can you add sample for your case  len([ID]) > 3. and  on which basis we decide to use PackId inital 'pk' or 'ab' or any random ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean with "It should accept any sequence" and "computed columns in INSERT statement"? A computed column is computed. That means it is not inserted. It makes no sense to insert a value into a computed column.

Comment: What I mean is I will not write that Computed Column logic While creating table How can I Use Same Logic  While Writing Insert statement @Sefe

Comment: @sai bharath can you add sample for your case len([ID]) > 3.

Comment: Edited Now Please Check Once again @Sefe

Comment: Here ID will have 1,2,3..... etc @Mr.Bhosale

Answer (score 2):

Since your `ID` column is not an identity column, you can simply use the statement in your computed column with your ID value (for better readability I assume you have a parameter @ID for your ID value):

```
INSERT INTO tblPacks (ID, PackID)
VALUES (
    @ID,
    CONVERT([varchar](50),'PK'+case when len(@ID)<=(3) then CONVERT([varchar](20),right((0.001)*@ID,(3)),0) else CONVERT([varchar](20),@ID,0) end,0)
)
```

If your `ID` column actually **is** an identity column, you need `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get your inserted ID value. However, since `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only gives you the ID **after** the value has been inserted, you need two steps. It is a good idea to use a transaction for these steps to make your operation atomic:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO tblPacks (ID) VALUES (@ID)

UPDATE tblPacks
SET PackID = CONVERT([varchar](50),'PK'+case when len(SCOPE_IDENTITY())<=(3) then CONVERT([varchar](20),right((0.001)*SCOPE_IDENTITY(),(3)),0) else CONVERT([varchar](20),SCOPE_IDENTITY(),0) end,0)
WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

COMMIT
```

You can also use a trigger on your table instead of a computed column that sets the value if you have not set it before:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_tblPacks ON tblPacks
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE tblPacks
    SET PackID = CONVERT([varchar](50),'PK'+case when len(inserted.ID)<=(3) then CONVERT([varchar](20),right((0.001)*inserted.ID,(3)),0) else CONVERT([varchar](20),inserted.ID,0) end,0)
    FROM inserted
    WHERE tblPacks.ID = inserted.ID AND tblPacks.PackID IS NULL
```

With this trigger you only add your custom value to the `INSERT` statement if you have it. If you don't have it, the trigger will set the default value.

Comment: Thanks For Your Explanation..I had a Doubt that If ID is not identity And Still I have to generate PackID Sequence in order like PK001,PK002 etc How can I DO this without Identity Column? @Sefe

Comment: @saibharath: Check the first code block in my post. This is how you do it with a non-identity ID column. The trigger version will work with the non-identity ID, too.

Comment: I think You didn't Get me,Let me Explain in details For example we take Trigger you wrote len(inserted.id)<=3 means if inserted.id is '1' then PackID is PK0001 Consdier this PK0001 As first record and next for second record Inserted.id id '5' then PackID Will be PK0005 But I want It to be PK0002 irrsepctive of inserted.id @Sefe

Comment: @saibharath: That is a different question. This question is how to replace a computed column with a logic that works with INSERT. I'd recommend you open another question for your other problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could set user defined function as computed column.like this..

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD YourColumn AS dbo.TestFunction(otherColumn);
```

then, you can include all your logic for this computed column in that user defined function.

Comment: Can You Please Explain More In Detail I didn't Get You @DarkKnight

Comment: Warning: I'm getting `Column names are not permitted` error when trying to pass a column to the UDF.   Managed it with Sefe's answer suggestion for Triggers.